# Configurar R para utilizar utf-8 por defecto

Tags: r

Para evitar problemas al usar R y RStudio, ¿se puede configurar R para que trabaje con utf-8 por defecto?, mi sistema es windows 10 64 bit, los scripts de R se guardan como ANSI, sin embargo, al abrir esos mismos archivos con RStudio hay problemas con los caracteres latinos, ñ, tildes, símbolo del euro €. Tengo que ir convirtiendo los archivos para cambiar la codificación de caracteres, y así poder utilizarlos con RStudio.

Desde la consola de R:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

lo que tienes que hacer es configurar un archivo llamado *.Rprofile*. Este archivo sirve para hacer configuraciones por defecto. El archivo ya existe, pero generalmente esta oculto. Debajo los pasos para que lo hagas en RStudio:

1. Ubicas el archivo usando el comando en R `file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile")`. Copias esa ruta.
2. `file.edit(file.path("pegas toda la ruta del archivo)` y se abrira un editor
3. Dentro del editor colocas `options(encoding = "utf-8")`
4. Guardas el archivo, cierras el RStudio y lo vuelves abrir para que se vean los cambios.

Eso seria todo.

Comment: gracias por responder, no tengo .Rprofile, la ruta en mi caso es: "C:\\Users\\JoséCarlos\\Documents/.Rprofile", y no se ejecuta el paso 2: file.edit(file.path("C:\\Users\\JoséCarlos\\Documents/.Rprofile")

Comment: Sin embargo, los valores de la sessionInfo() siguen siendo: 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252

Comment: El archivo no existía. Para crearlo he tenido que utilizar file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile")). En mi sistema la codificación sigue siendo ANSI.

Comment: Entiendo, a veces pasa eso en windows. Hay otra forma, pero es usando el RStudio. Vas a la pestaña Tools >> Global Options >> Code >> Saving , dentro ahi hay un combo llamado Default text enconding, ahi lo cambias por UTF-8. Me avisas que tal

Comment: Así lo tengo configurado en RStudio. Sin embargo, RStudio, sin esa configuración, ya funcionaba con utf-8 por defecto. De hecho, eso busco, la compatibilidad de los archivos creados con R en RStudio. De momento no encuentro forma alguna de hacer funcionar Rbase con utf-8 en windows 10 home 64 bit.